# Load jquery and SSL in Web View

Tags: java, android, jquery, google-chrome, ssl

Iam trying to load this page:

`http://festify.us/549f4d03493853f421cca45c`

in my webview, but my app crash and send this error:

```
05-09 04:14:03.989  10208-10234/dw5.djbronzinho A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 10234 (WebViewCoreThre)
```

researching thought it could be done with the WebChromeClient, but I can not put it in my code, can anyone help me ?

MainActive.java:

`package dw5.djbronzinho;`

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
```

`public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebView;`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mWebView = new WebView(this);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://festify.us/549f4d03493853f421cca45c/");
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    this.setContentView(mWebView);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}}`
```

MY FULL LOGCAT:

`05-09 15:39:15.661    3286-3286/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
05-09 15:39:15.831    3286-3286/dw5.djbronzinho D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
05-09 15:39:15.831    3286-3286/dw5.djbronzinho D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
05-09 15:39:15.831    3286-3286/dw5.djbronzinho D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
05-09 15:39:16.701    3286-3286/dw5.djbronzinho I/webclipboard﹕ clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@428f7150
05-09 15:39:16.971    3286-3286/dw5.djbronzinho D/WebView﹕ loadUrlImpl: called
05-09 15:39:17.201    3286-3286/dw5.djbronzinho D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
05-09 15:39:17.291    3286-3286/dw5.djbronzinho D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
05-09 15:39:17.291    3286-3286/dw5.djbronzinho D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
05-09 15:39:17.311    3286-3286/dw5.djbronzinho I/Adreno200-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.02.21.107_msm8625_JB_REL_2.0.3_CL3357771_release_AU (CL3357771)
    Build Date: 02/25/13 Mon
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/jb_rel_2.0.3
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.02.21.107 +  NOTHING
05-09 15:39:17.511    3286-3318/dw5.djbronzinho V/webkit﹕ BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {428f3038}
05-09 15:39:17.601    3286-3286/dw5.djbronzinho D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
05-09 15:39:17.611    3286-3286/dw5.djbronzinho D/WebView﹕ onSizeChanged - w:480 h:762
05-09 15:39:17.621    3286-3286/dw5.djbronzinho I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-09 15:39:17.641    3286-3318/dw5.djbronzinho D/webcore﹕ CORE loadUrl: called
05-09 15:39:17.641    3286-3318/dw5.djbronzinho D/webkit﹕ Firewall not null
05-09 15:39:17.641    3286-3318/dw5.djbronzinho D/webkit﹕ euler: isUrlBlocked = false
05-09 15:39:21.081    3286-3286/dw5.djbronzinho D/TilesManager﹕ new EGLContext from framework: 4f83efb0
05-09 15:39:21.081    3286-3286/dw5.djbronzinho D/GLWebViewState﹕ Reinit shader
05-09 15:39:21.361    3286-3286/dw5.djbronzinho D/GLWebViewState﹕ Reinit transferQueue
05-09 15:39:26.611    3286-3318/dw5.djbronzinho A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 3318 (WebViewCoreThre)`

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Can you test this code on another device? or if testing on emulator try testing it on actual device.

Comment: I run in BlueStack and work great!, but what I can do to run in Android since version 4.1?

Comment: I run any other site, but this one is impossible, maybe bcs its load an external content, someone can help-me please?

Comment: See the error is related to firmware. So if you shed some more light on your code plus manifest file, we could do test on our devices.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I will put my AndroidManifest on OP

Comment: See Dude, The links works well with my code and my moto-g 2. You better got to test it on live and latest device.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but, [This](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) could help you debug your webview as you debug your website in chrome's develper-tool.